# Ruby on rails devise form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm starting with ruby and rails and I want to create a helper to show this form :

```
<%= form_for( :user, :url => session_path( :user) ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  <%= f.submit 'Sign in' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path( :user) %>
<% end %>
```

So I just have to call function `show_login_form` and display the form but I don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`#concat`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat) helper method.

Put following method in some helper:

```
def show_login_form
  form_for(:user, :url => session_path( :user) ) do |f|
    concat f.text_field :email
    concat f.password_field :password
    concat f.check_box :remember_me
    concat f.label :remember_me
    concat f.submit 'Sign in'
    concat link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path( :user)
  end
end
```

And call his from your views like:

```
<%= show_login_form %>
```